# How I can get "name" under the "language" attribute of this JSONArray?

Tags: java, android, json

I use a Web-API for a Android App. But I have a problem to get "name" from the attribute "languages".

For the "name" of country I used:

```
protected String parseJSON(String jsonString) throws Exception {

    if (jsonString == null || jsonString.trim().length() == 0) {

        return "empty Object";
    }
    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);

    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");

    return name;
}
```

How I can get "name" under the "language" attribute of this JSONArray?
https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/spain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
JSONArray languages = jsonObject.getJSONArray("languages");
String firstLanguageName = languages.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
```

Even though I strongly encourage you using [gson](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson.html) instead of parsing this way, gson makes life easier when parsing json.

Answer (score 1):

I use this maven dependency for parsing JSON: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple

Using that, the method you are looking for would be:

```
protected String parseJSON(String jsonString) throws Exception {
    if (jsonString == null || jsonString.trim().length() == 0) {
        return "empty Object";
    }

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) ((JSONArray) parser.parse(jsonString)).get(0);
    JSONObject language = (JSONObject) ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("languages")).get(0);
    return (String) language.get("name");
}
```

Assuming that you only care about the first language in that json, as the "languages" object is an array.